# How to label rows by unique pairs of other rows in pandas 0.19.2

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` like this but much larger.

```
  ID_0 ID_1  location
0    a    b     1
1    a    c     1
2    a    b     0
3    d    c     0
4    a    c     0
5    a    c     1
```

I would like to add a column which identifies the first two. For example:

```
  ID_0 ID_1  location group_ID
0    a    b     1     0
1    a    c     1     1
2    a    b     0     0
3    d    c     0     2
4    a    c     0     1
5    a    c     1     1
```

This new column comes from the mapping "a b" to 0, "a c" to 1 and "d c" to 2.

I think the first stage to do this is

```
grouped  = df.groupby(['ID_0', 'ID_1'])
```

but I am not sure where to go from there.

> How can you make this new column in pandas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html), new in `0.20.2`:

```
df['group_ID'] = df.groupby(['ID_0', 'ID_1']).ngroup()
print (df)
  ID_0 ID_1  location  group_ID
0    a    b         1         0
1    a    c         1         1
2    a    b         0         0
3    d    c         0         2
4    a    c         0         1
5    a    c         1         1
```

---

```
df['group_ID'] = df.groupby(['ID_0', 'ID_1']).grouper.group_info[0]
print (df)
  ID_0 ID_1  location  group_ID
0    a    b         1         0
1    a    c         1         1
2    a    b         0         0
3    d    c         0         2
4    a    c         0         1
5    a    c         1         1
```

Comment: Thanks! I had no  idea that existed. What can you do in pandas 0.19.2?

Comment: I am not sure the setup I will be using will have 0.20.x sadly.

Comment: No possible upgrade?

Comment: That might be difficult to negotiate with the others working on the project. We have 0.19.2 currently.

Comment: OK, gice me some time

Comment: Makes you wonder why they bothered with ngroup if grouper.group_info[0] is a drop-in replacement !  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick without using the `GroupBy.ngroup` which is only supported in newer `pandas` versions:

```
df['group_ID'] = df.groupby(['ID_0', 'ID_1']).grouper.group_info[0]

    ID_0    ID_1    location    group_ID
0   a       b       1           0
1   a       c       1           1
2   a       b       0           0
3   d       c       0           2
4   a       c       0           1
```

Find more information at this SO post: [Python Pandas: How can I group by and assign an id to all the items in a group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063251/python-pandas-how-can-i-group-by-and-assign-an-id-to-all-the-items-in-a-group)

Comment: Oh nice you found a dupe

Comment: Woops! By the time I was writing this answer I guess someone else already answered it! Good catch